# How to get all Ephemeral Nodes and how long they have existed in a Zookeeper Server?

Tags: java, nodes, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I know about terminal commands like - `echo mntr | nc localhost port` which can return me the count of Ephemeral Nodes. 
But what I need to do is, I need to check how long each Ephemeral Node has persisted on the server and to report an error if any Ephemeral Node has persisted above a particular time limit.
I can traverse the entire tree using recursion, but this will help only if I can check if the node is an Ephemeral Node and how long it has existed.

Any framework or method which can enable me to check how long each Ephemeral Node has persisted using Java code? I could not find any API or framework which could return me such metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Check `org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData`
which returns not only the byte array, but also the `Stat`: c(reated)/m(odified)time, and ephemeralOwner (isEphemeral if value != 0)

Comment: But I will still have to traverse all nodes in the server, which takes a lot of time. I am looking for something quicker.